# Jboss Fuse and Cobertura

Tags: cobertura, jbossfuse

I have my application which runs in Jboss Fuse on Linux. I deploy my artifacts as jar files under the /deploy directory. I was planning to make use of Cobertura to get code coverage report after executing my jmeter tests. I instrumented my jars and placed under /deploy. I ran my jmeter tests.

Now I am unable to find  the location where `.ser` file will be present. 
I tried searching inside fuse directory.

Can anyone help me in getting Cobertura working with Jboss Fuse?

Answer (score 0):

For most versions of Cobertura, you can add:

```
 -Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=<filename>.ser
```

to the JBoss/JVM startup parameters (e.g. run.conf) to specify explicitly the file where you want the report to be created.

Also, you need to make sure the cobertura.jar itself is present in the classpath if you haven't done so yet.

Comment: Thanks Patrice, I cant find run.conf.  I made changes as follows.
in bash_profile  i have cobertura-2.1.1.jar added in path.I also have -Dnet.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile=/tmp/c.s mentioned in JAVA_OPTS.After these changes i did source .bash_profile and started fuse in same terminal and ran my automation scripts. I cant see file /tmp/c.s generated.   Any idea what other changes will be required ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiar with JBoss Fuse, but I think you need to somehow make sure JAVA_OPTS is taken into account when it starts up. For the cobertura.jar, you meant added to the classpath, right? Not the PATH which won't give you anything. Typically you can drop it in to some server lib folder, OR package it into your application archive, if that helps.